# Accessing a specific Angular Element by Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bots, ng-show, ng-hide

So I'm creating a bot for an exploit I found in a website.

This website has 3 buttons.

- 1. To check if you enter the correct answer
- 2. The submit button
- 3. The magic button which gives you the answers if you entered the wrong answer 3 times (Which is easily exploitable by just changing it's class from "ng-hide" to "ng-show"

**So here's the code.**

```
<div class="activityPanel-actions" ng-hide="pageState.type == 'ASSESSMENT' ||      pageState.type == 'LESSON_ASSESSMENT'">
        <div ng-show="isViewAnswerButtonVisible(progress, externalInterAction)">
            <button class="button button-primary" ng-disabled="isViewAnswerButtonDisabled(progress)" ng-click="showStudentAnswer()" disabled="disabled">Show my answer</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isSubmitButtonVisible(progress)" class="ng-hide">
            <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="checkActivity($event)" ng-disabled="ebForm.invalid">Check: is answer correct?</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isShowCorrectAnswerButtonVisible(progress)" class="ng-hide">
            <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="showCorrectAnswerForActivity(externalInterAction)" ng-disabled="isShowCorrectAnswerButtonDisabled()">Show correct answers</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

**And here is my Jquery code right now.**

```
   // I'm adding the Ng-show class to all the classes that have ng-hide
    $(".activityPanel-actions .ng-hide").addClass("ng-show"); 

    // i"m removing the old ng-hide class because it now has ng-show
    $(".activityPanel-actions .ng-hide").removeClass("ng-hide");

    // Now I'm clicking all the buttons in the activityPanel-actions div.
    $(".activityPanel-actions .ng-show button").trigger('click');

    // Adding the ng-hide class back so that the buttons hide.
    $(".activityPanel-actions .ng-show").addClass("ng-hide");

    // Deleting the ng-show class so that is now properly hidden
    $(".activityPanel-actions .ng-show").removeClass("ng-show");
```

But here is my problem:

It is not only changing the ng-hide to ng-show class on the "Show correct answer" div. 
But it's changing them on every div.
Also it is not only clicking the button which shows the answer but it's randomly clicking every button!

So I want it to only show the "Show correct answer div" and hide the "Check answer" div.

And than I also only want to click the button that I want, and than after that is done of course I want to hide the proper div.

Can somebody please help me with this?
I've been struggling for a long time now!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can be done easily using pure AngularJS. Show us the relevant view and relevant parts from the controller

Comment: God my brain hurts even seeing this. It's never a good idea to mix JQuery and Angular.